# Access Shopify Collection metafields via linklist

Tags: html, for-loop, metadata, shopify, liquid

I am looking to show a custom field (using the app Shopify Custom Fields) to show another image other than the collection image (we cannot use the collection image for reasons that are too long to write about). Right now using the custom field which is a text field (which we have as an absolute URL to the image we want to use) here:

```
<img src="{{ collection.metafields.custom_fields["collection_list_image_url"] }}" alt="{{ link.title }}"/>
```

To get the Collection image like normal, which does work I used:

```
<img src="{{ link.object.image.src | collection_img_url: 'master' }}" alt="{{ link.title }}"/>
```

For some reason the image is not showing up and after inspection it says img src is unknown.  It does work if we use the normal collection image though.  Is there something I need to add to get this custom field to show up dynamically for each collection in the menu nav (link list)?

I have the following code written:

```
<div class="collection-list">
  {% for link in linklists.collection-list.links %}
    <div class="box">
      <a href="{{ link.url }}">
        <img src="{{ collection.metafields.custom_fields["collection_list_image_url"] }}" alt="{{ link.title }}"/>    
         <div class="heading">
           <h2>{{ link.title }}</h2>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">shop now</button>
         </div>
       </a>
     </div>
   {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

Comment: It does not look like your code shows any kind of loop whereby the actual collection with metafield resources is set. In the code you show, what is collection? If you could reveal that, you'd probably see why your images are not showing up.

Comment: The collection is based on the collection selected in the Nav Menu (collection-list) which is referenced in the for.

Comment: Update the question with the code I used to get the normal collection image to dynamically show as well.

Comment: `src="{{ link.object.metafields.custom_fields['collection_list_image_url'] }}"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `link.object` (and maybe account for the fact that it might not be a Collection). Nesting single quotes within the double quotes when you reference the metafield key is also better syntax:

```
<div class="collection-list">
  {% for link in linklists.collection-list.links %}
    {% if link.object == 'collection' %}
      {% assign cf = link.object.metafields.custom_fields %}
      <div class="box">
        <a href="{{ link.url }}">
          <img src="{{ cf['collection_list_image_url'] }}" alt="{{ link.title }}">
          <div class="heading">
            <h2>{{ link.title }}</h2>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">shop now</button>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```