# How do I access metafields on a collection when hoveringen on the collection in the menu in shopify prestige theme?

Tags: loops, dynamic, menu, shopify, liquid

I want to add dynamic pictures to my shopify site, using the prestige theme.
So when i hover on a collection from the main menu, I want to show the metafield on the collection inside the main menu, just like in this example:
https://shapingnewtomorrow.dk/

My code looks the following, and only shows the dynamic image when i am on the url of the collection, which has the meta data field:

```
<div class="DropdownMenu flex-menu" aria-hidden="true">
                    <ul class="Linklist">
                      {%- for sub_link in link.links -%}
                        <li class="Linklist__Item" {% if sub_link.links != blank %}aria-haspopup="true"{% endif %}>
                          <a href="{{ sub_link.url }}" class="Link Link--secondary">{{ sub_link.title | escape }} {% if sub_link.links != blank %}{% render 'icon' with 'select-arrow-right' %}{% endif %}</a>
                          {%- if sub_link.links != blank -%}
                            <div class="DropdownMenu" aria-hidden="true">
                              <ul class="Linklist">
                                {%- for sub_sub_link in sub_link.links -%}
                                
                                  <li class="Linklist__Item">
                                  
                                    <a href="{{ sub_sub_link.url }}" class="Link Link--secondary">{{ sub_sub_link.title | escape }}</a>
                                  </li>
                                {%- endfor -%}
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                          {%- endif -%}
                        </li>
                      {%- endfor -%}
                    </ul>
                   
                     <div class="rel-container">
                         <img src="{{collection.metafields.custom.menuimage}}" 
                           alt="garnheader" style="width:880px;height:60vh;">
                         <div class="bottom-left">
                           <h2> {{collection.metafields.my_fields.introheader}} </h2>
                           <p>  {{collection.metafields.my_fields.introtekst}} </p>
                           <a href="{{ sub_link.url }}"> Køb nu</button>
                         </div>
                     <div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the collection object so you cannot call the objects metafields. You need to loop through the link list and if the link is of type collection then reference link.object before being able to access the metafield data.

````
  {% for link in linklists.collection-list.links %}
    {% if link.object == 'collection' %}
      {% assign collectionObjectMetafields = link.object.metafields.custom_fields %}
        <img src="{{ collectionObjectMetafields['collection_list_image_url'] }}" alt="{{ link.title }}">
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526367/access-shopify-collection-metafields-via-linklist
````

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I tried added the following, but it didnt allow me to access metafield data. 
Is it possible when I hover on the existing menu that it shows the image from the custom meta field on the collection?

Comment: This is too complex to figure out without seeing exactly what you are doing in the code, but you should be able to access the link sources' metafields with the above method, then store the image src from the metafield in a data-attribute or something and then use some javascript to swap the src of the default image with the src of the collection you are hovering on. You could also use the collection's featured image it doesn't have to be a metafield it would use the same method.